# The use of /D (number) inside /A action on PDF specification language

Tags: pdf, iso-32000

what is the purpose of `/D (a number)` inside /A action dictionary inside an annotation dictionary, on PDF specification language, how is its mechanism works
...

```
218 0 obj
<< /Type /ObjStm /Length 8647 /N 100 /First 889 >>
stream
219 0 220 116 221 237 222 353 223 470 224 587 225 704 226 820 227 936 228 1053
<< /A << /D (116) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 624.06 450 631.636 ] /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
<< /A << /D (117) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 426.336 591.183 450.545 603.935 ]     /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
<< /A << /D (117) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 575.413 450 585.11 ] /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
<< /A << /D (117) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 564.384 450 571.959 ] /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
<< /A << /D (118) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 551.233 450 558.809 ] /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
<< /A << /D (118) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 538.082 450 545.658 ] /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
<< /A << /D (119) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 522.81 450 532.507 ] /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
<< /A << /D (119) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 509.66 450 519.357 ] /Subtype /Link /Type /Annot >>
```

...

while no `/D ( )` explained in Action on PDF ISO32000-2 reference, i.e:

> 12.6.2 Action dictionaries    An action dictionary defines the characteristics and behaviour of an action. "Table 196: Entries common
> to all action dictionaries" shows the required and optional entries
> that are common to all action dictionaries. The dictionary may contain
> additional entries specific to a particular action type; see the
> descriptions of individual action types in 12.6.4, "Action types" for
> details.
>
> Table 196: Entries common to all action dictionaries
>
> Key       Type          Value
>
> Type      name          (Optional) The type of PDF object that this
> dictionary
> describes; if present, shall be Action for an action
> dictionary.
> S        name          (Required) The type of action that this dictionary
> describes;   see "Table 201: Action types" for specific values.
> Next      dictionary/array (Optional; PDF 1.2)
> The next action or sequence of
> actions that shall be performed after the action represented by this dictionary. The value is either a
> single action dictionary or an array of action dictionaries that shall
> be performed in order; see Note 1 for further discussion.
>
> NOTE 1 The action dictionary’s Next entry (PDF 1.2) allows sequences
> of actions to be chained together. For example, the effect of clicking
> a link annotation with the mouse might be to play a sound, jump to a
> new page, and start up a movie. Note that the Next entry is not
> restricted to a single action but may contain an array of actions,
> each of which in turn may have a Next entry of its own. The actions
> may thus form a tree instead of a simple linked list. Actions within
> each Next array are executed in order, each followed in turn by any
> actions specified in its Next entry, and so on recursively. It is
> recommended that interactive PDF processors attempt to provide
> reasonable behaviour in anomalous situations. For example,
> self-referential actions ought not be executed more than once, and
> actions that close the document or otherwise render the next action
> impossible ought to terminate the execution sequence. Applications
> need also provide some mechanism for the user to interrupt and
> manually terminate a sequence of actions. PDF 1.5 introduces
> transition actions, which allow the control of drawing during a
> sequence of actions; see 12.6.4.15, "Transition actions". NOTE 2 It is
> recommended that no action modify its own action dictionary or any
> other in the action tree in which it resides. The effect of such
> modification on subsequent execution of actions in the tree is
> undefined.

Please help shed a bright light

Comment: *"while no /D ( ) explained in Action on PDF ISO32000-2 reference"* - for the **D** entry don't look at the "Entries common to all action dictionaries" but at the "Additional Entries specific to an embedded go-to action".

Comment: (116) isn't a number, it's a string. As K J hints, you need to look at the Subtype of the Action, which is a GoTo, then look at what a GoTo Action expects. If you do that, you'll see that 'D' is a possible key in a remote GoTo action, and is defined as a name, byte string, or array.